# Looking for a form component to select a period of time

Tags: forms, time

I'm currently working on a very long form (can't be shortened) which I'm trying to make a bit more playful and easy to fill.

There are a lot of radio buttons, which is ok in terms of usability, but a bit boring for the user.

**Do you have any idea how I could present the following type of question / answer in a more visual way?**
[image: choosing a range of time]

There are other questions with percentages such as this one:
[image: choosing a range of percentage]

Anything I've tried so far seems to make the user's job more difficult but my client really wants something cool and visual.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a handy range selection control:
[image: Range selection control]
[image: Range selection control - modern]

In case the image URLs go obsolete:

### How long are you planning to stay on Mars?

in years ~~~~~~~~~~V==================V~~~~~~~~~~

______ 0__________1_________2_________3__________4

Suggestions:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAgn0H.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot for this proposal however I feel like it's giving too much choice  and work to the user : they have to set the ranges themselves instead of selecting one that's already suggested.
We don't need a very precise range. We want them to be able to select one of the proposals quickly

Comment: @RaphaëlleM - Added a Suggestions section (for quick access)

Comment: That's a good idea, it's at least as simple as radio buttons. In fact it's better because the left to right order works with the fact that the numbers are getting higher.
It's probably not as graphical as what the client would like but it works for me. Thanks